# React: make a cycle-through component with both forward and backward directions using Generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-generator

I have an array of strings to display `const array = ["one", "two", "three"];` .

The UI initially shows the first item in the array i.e. `"one"`. From there I have a button `right` when clicked it shows the next item or string which is `two`, and then `three`, after `three` it should go back to `one` and start from there again.
I also have a `left` button, when clicked it shows the previous item or string, if the current string is `two`, the previous string is `one`, and then after `one` it starts from `three` and walks backward.

I am using generator to do it. Here is my attempt

```js
function* stepGen(steps) {
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    const direction = yield steps[index];
    index = (index + (direction === "forward" ? 1 : -1)) % steps.length;
  }
}

const array = ["one", "two", "three"];
let gen = stepGen(array);
const getNext = () => gen.next("forward").value;
const getPrev = () => gen.next("backward").value;

export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(() => getNext());
  const onRight = () => {
    const next = getNext();
    setCurrent(next);
  };
  const onLeft = () => {
    const prev = getPrev();
    setCurrent(prev);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{current}</h1>
      <button onClick={onLeft}>left</button>
      <button onClick={onRight}>right</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a live demo you can play with
https://codesandbox.io/s/cyclethrough1-deh8p?file=/src/App.js

Apparently the current behavior is buggy. There are multiple issues that I don't know the causes and the solutions:

1. **the UI starts with `two` not `one`**. I guess it has something to do with how I initiate my state `current`

```js
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(() => getNext());
```

I thought `() => getNext()` is only to get called once when the component first mounts so `current` should be `one` from the start.

And I tried to initiated the state with

```js
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(array[0]);
```

It indeed starts with the first item in the array which is `one` but you have to click `right` button twice to make it go to `two`. Here is the live demo for this variation https://codesandbox.io/s/cyclethrough2-5gews?file=/src/App.js

2. the `left` button, which should walk backward the loop doesn't work. It is broken completely. the `right` button works though. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `getPrev` is the [remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), which unlike the modulo operation returns a negative result when the remainder is negative. To solve that use a modulo function instead:

```
// modulo function
const mod = (n, r) => ((n % r) + r) % r;
```

To solve the problem on the 1st render create the initial value outside of the component. This is a workaround, since I can't find the reason for that bug.

```
const init = getNext(); // get the initial value

export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(init); // use init value
```

I would also save the need for a ternary to determine the increment by passing `1` and `-1` in `getNext` and `getPrev` respectively.

Full code example ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wildflower-p2e0c)):

```
// modulo function
const mod = (n, r) => ((n % r) + r) % r;

function* stepGen(steps) {
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    const dir = yield steps[index];
    index = mod(index + dir, steps.length); // use mod function instead of remainder operator
  }
}

const array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const gen = stepGen(array);

const getPrev = () => gen.next(-1).value; // dec directly
const getNext = () => gen.next(1).value; // inc directly

const init = getNext(); // get the initial value

export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(init); // use init value

  const onLeft = () => {
    const next = getPrev();
    setCurrent(next);
  };

  const onRight = () => {
    const prev = getNext();
    setCurrent(prev);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{current}</h1>
      <button onClick={onLeft}>left</button>
      <button onClick={onRight}>right</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed with the remainder (%) operator, and use `const mod = (n, r) => ((n % r) + r) % r;` instead would fix it.

I wanted to answer my own questions because I think I understand what were causing the weird issues with the initial state.

1. For the issue with the UI starting with two not one, it was caused by the double rendering of React's strict mode.
2. And then if we use `const [current, setCurrent] = useState(array[0]);` instead, there would be another problem where you need to double click on `right` to make it go to `two`. This is because in the generator, `index` starts at 0, so after first click, the iterator would yield the current `index` which is `0` not `1`, therefore we need to double click it to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

So, my proposed answer is:

1. For one, as one of the answers has mentioned, it is caused by a double render. My proposal is to not initialise the value in `useState` but in the `useEffect` hook with empty dependencies. This will cause it to run only once on the first render. Example:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrent(() => getNext())
  }, [])
```

2. The bug is caused by the fact that you are subtracting 1 from the index. When its in the position 0, it leads to index of -1 which is does not yield an item. A simple solution is to loop the index back to the last element if its negative.

```js
function* stepGen(steps) {
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    const direction = yield steps[index];
    index = (index + (direction === "forward" ? 1 : -1)) % steps.length;
    if (index < 0) {
      index = steps.length - 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Interesting so the callback in `setState` is going to be invoked doubly inf strict mode but the callback in `useEffect` will not? didn't know that.

Comment: @Joji Exactly, useEffect gets called when the items in the dependency array are updated. If you pass an empty array as a dependency, it will only run on the initial render. I feel like this is a pretty comprehensive explanation of this https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/

Answer (score 0):

Use the logging of the js like window.log() [image]It is clearly visible that the bug is after clicking left the number generated are -2 -1 which are not array indexes so one idea can be to make them positive.But the first step is to find the bug